# Problem after migration TFS 2010 to TFS 2017

Tags: tfs

I upgraded TFS from version 2010 -> TFS 2013 Update 5 -> to TFS 2017.3.1. The migration was successful, without errors.

When we select any work item we get error:

TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred.

{"message":"TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred.","type":"System.NullReferenceException"}

[image]

Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-vLDQ_BPnMflh1yV4rhP43SsHlun31XvwYB1svh7haP9E=:5 GET http://servr_name:8080/Colection/sssdddd59ad7c58-da11-49ed-a085-6acc62384a85/_api/_wit/workItemTypes?__v=5&typeNames=FDR&stamp=5-12c3sss1sss162-12c40e0-117e5b3-12c4b45-11884ddddsaf-12c4b4b-1sss2c3166-117e5c2-ffffdddsffff826b3e0c-0-0-stateColors-True 500 (Internal Server Error)

It looks like api can't read domain users who own the work item.

This is not a TFS cache issue because it has been cleared on the client and server.

It depends on the users. eg, TFS administrator does not have such an error, work item opens correctly.

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: Are they able to open work items in other projects or other project collections? Did this issue only occur in this specific team project?

Comment: The problem also occurs in other projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2**

OP finally re-graduated 2010 to 2017 without the following command and it seems to have helped.

```
TFSConfig ChangeServerID /SQLInstance:server_db /DatabaseName:TFS_Configuration
```

---

First check Event Log in Event Viewer to see whether there is some useful information.

For the migration, make sure there are not any databases left from another TFS instance. Cleaning these up should help.

> It depends on the users. eg, TFS administrator does not have such an
>   error, work item opens correctly.

If this issue depends on users. That may related to permission sync up.

You could try to remove all users out of the project and add them back again. Which may do the trick.

Also double check the permission related settings. Whether they are added under an area with deny permission for security settings. Since in TFS, deny trumps allow.

---

**Update**

If the upgrade was successful without any errors. Then this kind of error may related to the configuration.

You could try **re-running the configuration wizard** for the team project to fix the issue. How to please refer this tutorial: [Configure features after an upgrade](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade)

Comment: Authorizations have been checked many times. It's not helping.
Unable to load user field, and EventViewer loops have:
TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation component or extension:
Exception Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (type NullReferenceException)
Because the field is treated as empty.

Comment: Hi @Ebasse Thanks for your quick response. According to your error message, did you install any 3rd-party extensions which may cause this issue. Suggest you give a try with disabling them  temporarily and check if this do the trick.

Comment: Besides, If the upgrade was successful without any errors. Then this kind of erorr may related to the configuration.

You could try **re-running the configuration wizard** for the team project to fix the issue. How to please refer this tutorial: [Configure features after an upgrade](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade)

Comment: I have disabled add-ons for the collection and no changes. Similarly, if reconfiguration is performed. The problem persists.

Comment: Hi @Ebasse Thanks for your quick response, what about reattached the whole collection database? Also restart the server and related job service. If this still not work. You may have to file a support ticket https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/devops/ at the bottom of the page Premium technical support. Since this is a open site.

Comment: Hi @Ebasse Any update on this issue, just checking to see if the information provided was helpful.

Comment: Disconnecting and reconnecting did not help. I re-graduated 2010 to 2017 without the following command and it seems to have helped. The question is why the problem is them: "TFSConfig ChangeServerID /SQLInstance:server_db /DatabaseName:TFS_Configuration". Maybe in the migration process before this command I should use an additional command. What do you think?

Comment: Hi @Ebasse Thanks for your upgrade, glad to hear this. The **changeServerID** command changes the GUIDs that are associated with the databases for Azure DevOps Server. GUIDs must be unique within a deployment of Azure DevOps Server.  You would not typically use this command in daily operations, you might use this command in the following circumstances:
You restored your deployment to new hardware, the old deployment is still **operational**, and you want to utilize both deployments. This scenario is sometimes referred to as **cloning the server**. No need to use this command in your situation

Comment: Besides, there is no additional command to use before this. To use the changeServerID command, you must be a member of the Azure DevOps Administrators security group and a member of the sysadmin security role for all SQL Server instances that Azure DevOps Server uses.  **Note:**

You use the changeServerID command to create a discrete duplicate of a deployment of Azure DevOps Server for testing or cloning purposes. **After you use the changeServerID command, you must direct clients to create a connection to the changed server before it can be used.** This may cause your issue. Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it necessary to execute the changeServerID command when moving the database to another database server and then performing the TFS upgrade from version 2010 to 2017? I understand not.

Comment: Hi Ebasse, no, it's no necessary to do this. Since this kind of upgrade, we usually abandon the old TFS 2010 server and database. Unless you want keep TFS 2010 server online and working on it. Then since there are two databases, you need to execute the changeServerID command to change one of them.

Comment: Ok. I just wonder why this command can cause an error after migration.

Comment: Not pretty sure about the root cause, after you use the changeServerID command, you must direct clients to create a connection to the changed server before it can be used. I was if there is something in database cached, kind like the queries are still point to the old Server ID. But the actually server ID is the updated new one.  Which may cause 500 (Internal Server Error)  issue.

Comment: thank you very much for the tips in solving the problem